# Finding unique rows for some columns in a matrix with values of remaining columns being preserved

Tags: r

I have a matrix which has unique rows for a few columns but not for all columns. I know there are many ways of finding unique rows but I need something in addition. I want to find unique rows in the matrix excluding the last column of the matrix. The values of the last column for unique rows should be recorded in newly generated columns according to the number of unique rows. For illustration, see the example of R code bellow:

```
M <- matrix(c(rep(4:6,2),rep(1:3,2),seq(0.1,0.6,0.1)),6,3)
> colnames(M)=c("s1","s2","p")
> unique(M[,1:2])
     s1 s2
[1,]  4  1
[2,]  5  2
[3,]  6  3
```

But I need output matrix something like this

```
      s1 s2 p1  p2
[1,]  4  1  0.1 0.4
[2,]  5  2  0.2 0.5
[3,]  6  3  0.3 0.6
```

new columns `p1,p2,...,p6` can be created according to maximum number of repeatition in the matrix `M` for a unique row.

Feel free to ask if the question is not clear. Thanks in advance.

Comment: this is reshape ..

Answer (score 1):

This can be done using `spread` from `dplyr`

```
as.tibble(M) %>% 
group_by(s1, s2) %>% 
mutate(index = row_number()) %>% 
ungroup() %>%
spread(index, p)
```

As @WeNYoBen stated, it requires a reshape as the simplest solution, and this is one form of it.